# Contar las palabras con vocales

Tags: java, string

Se trata de una funcion para contar las palabras que empiezen con una vocal y terminen con esta misma vocal, pero solo obtengo un error.

esta es la funcion

```
public int vocal2 (Frase f) {
    StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer (f.getOracion());
    int i=0;

    while (tk.hasMoreTokens()) {
        char inicial = tk.nextToken().charAt(0);
        int fil = (tk.nextToken().length()-1);
        char cfinal = tk.nextToken().charAt(fil);
        if (inicial == 'a' || inicial == 'e' || inicial == 'i' || inicial == 'o' || inicial == 'u') {
            if (inicial == cfinal) {
                i++;
            }
        }

    }

    return i;
}
```

[image: El error que devuelve]

Comment: Cada vez que haces `tk.nextToken()` estas obteniendo una nueva palabra por lo que al hacer el charAt estas haciendolo sobre una palabra distinta a la calculada.

Answer (score 1):

El problema parece ser que llamas varias veces a `tk.nextToken()`, y cada vez mueve al siguiente token, con lo cual puede producir errores de índice en la localización de los caracteres y falla al recorrer las palabras. Si guardas la palabra o token en una variable intermedia funciona sin problemas.
Te pongo un ejemplo.

```
StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer("la casa azul del este");
        int i=0;

    while (tk.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String word = tk.nextToken();
        char inicial = word.charAt(0);
        //System.out.println(inicial);
        int fil = (word.length()-1);
        char cfinal = word.charAt(fil);
        //System.out.println(cfinal);
        if (inicial == 'a' || inicial == 'e' || inicial == 'i' || inicial == 'o' || inicial == 'u') {
            if (inicial == cfinal) {
              i++;
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println(i); //imprime 1
```